# How to add item in the jTable combobox without reloading the frame

Tags: java, swing

I'm developing an application for myself where I want to Insert **Add New Item** form data to database first, then populate **Item Name** in the combobox of another frame jTable without reloading the frame. Please  help me to write the  code regarding this issue.

[image]

Comment: Post the code you've attempted to write in your question.  Otherwise, use the model / view / controller pattern to separate your concerns and focus on one part of your application at a time.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: Your "Add New Item" dialog just needs a reference to the combo box used as the editor. Then you just invoke the `addItem(…)` method of the comb box when you click the `Add` button.